# Does Krita have a "Transform" or "Warp" layer option?

Tags: layers, texture, krita, distort, layer-composition

I'm getting accustomed to Krita, and I'm at a point where I need to warp some line art. It would be convenient if I could keep the original, as well—at the moment, I'm simply duplicating the normal-mode master line art layer, muting it, and working on the duplicate with the distort brushes.

I kept thinking about the many render layer options, though, and it occurred to me that it might be possible to have one which simply distorts the layers below, like encoding an underlying UV offset? Mute it, I have the original art below it; unmute it, and all of the encoded distortions and scrapes apply? Does such a layer type exist at this time? I feel like it should exist, but I'm not entirely sure what to look for.

In the mean while I'm going to continue with the aforementioned Cave Man method of duplicating the layer.

Comment: Not asked, but GIMP has something you maybe can use. It's a mapping filter named Displace. See this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VC0P1668IMc But the deformed layer is changed , so you must keep also an untouched copy of the layer under deformations. I have seen this property wished to be implemented in Krita, too. in Krita forums. I guess you expect more, you want a live effect - mangle the deformation map and see the result in the fly and this all without making permanent changes to the original drawing.

Comment: @user287001 That's very similar to what I have in mind, but you're right, I'm looking for something real-time on a rendering layer. Think of a displacement vector mapped onto a color. It would be easy enough to do, I might try and implement it myself—I wrote a book on GIMP extensions back in 2020, but I've never done anything for Krita and I really like how well it gets along with my Wacom. Too many projects at once...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for "Transform Masks", which are layer masks that you can add to any layer.

1. Have a paint layer you want to transform
2. Go to Layers panel and click the down arrow button to the right of the "+" add new layer icon.
3. Select "Transform Mask". This will create the transform mask and become the active layer.
4. Select the Transform tool (`Ctrl+T` is default hotkey)
5. Modify the transform tool settings and image to get the transform you want and then click apply
6. You can simply click the visibility of the Transform Mask to turn on and off.

I suspect this is also be applicable to Groups Layers.

---

References

- Krita Docs on Transform Maks: https://docs.krita.org/en/reference_manual/layers_and_masks/transformation_masks.html
- Krita Docs on Transform Tool: https://docs.krita.org/en/reference_manual/tools/transform.html
- Krita Docs on Group Layers: https://docs.krita.org/en/reference_manual/layers_and_masks/group_layers.html

Comment: Thank you, I found transform masks and they're helpful for bulk movement; however, they're inadequate when I want to reversible wasp something in a potentially non-affine manner.